# Using tapply in a function/loop that will replace variable name for the length of the columns of the dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, statistics, tapply

In R, I have a dataset (which I call star) of records with about 50 appended demographics (each demographic can be called var1, var2, var3, etc). I have split the dataset in ~10% groups by using the following command:

```
star$cut=cut2(star$var1, g=10)
```

Then I used

```
tapply(star$RESPCODE, star$cut, mean)
```

to calculate the response rate of each of the ten groups.

I am simply trying to run a loop or a function that will execute these two commands so that I do not manually have to replace each variable name. I want var1 to be replaced with var2, var3, var4, etc. with this function/loop.

I am a beginner with writing code so be gentle. For the output, I would simply like something that I can copy and paste into Excel easily using the text-to-columns feature if need be (so probably some kind of a table).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
varN = 1:10
res = vector("list")
for (n in varN) 
  star[,paste("cut",n,sep="")] = cut2(star[,paste("var",n,sep=""), g=10)
  res[n] = tapply(star$RESPCODE, star[,paste("cut",n,sep="")], mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is `mapply`, and the return is a list object.

```
mapply(function(x, dd) {
         dd$cut <- cut2(dd[, x], g=10)
         tapply(dd$RESPCODE, dd$cut, mean)
       }, c('var1', 'var2', 'var3'), MoreArg=list(dd=star), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```